I can't seem to get a function in one class to properly call a function in another class in tkinter - Python
I am having trouble getting this text box to print text when the button from Class3 is pressed. If I call the same function from Class2 then everything is fine. But from Class 3 not so much. I can still call the function (It even prints to the console) But it does not change the Text window. Can't figure out what I am missing. I am still learning classes in python so having trouble phrasing my questions online to get the desired results.
import tkinter as tk

def mainGUI():
    app = Class1()
    app.mainloop()
    

class Class1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.title("test")
        frame1 = Class2(self)
        frame1.pack()
        frame2 = Class3(self)
        frame2.pack()


class Class2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Class2 Button', command=self.doStuff)
        button1.pack()

        self.text_box = tk.Text(self)
        self.text_box.pack()

    def doStuff(self):
        self.text_box.insert(tk.END, "You Pushed the button!\n")
        print("I can print to console though")


class Class3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Class3 Button', command=Class2(parent).doStuff)
        button2.pack()

mainGUI()


Class2 and Class3 are both passed the root object.  They shouldn't need to know anything about each other -- any connections should happen in the root class.
Remember, you need to call a method of that OBJECT, not just the class.  What you are doing now is creating a brand new Class2 object in the callback -- it's not the Class2 object you created above.  If Class3 needs to send to Class2, the proper way is to have Class3 call a callback in the root, and have the root forward that to people who need it.  For example:
import tkinter as tk

def mainGUI():
    app = Class1()
    app.mainloop()
    

class Class1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.title("test")
        self.frame1 = Class2(self)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2 = Class3(self)
        self.frame2.pack()

    def class3_button(self):
        self.frame1.doStuff()


class Class2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Class2 Button', command=self.doStuff)
        button1.pack()

        self.text_box = tk.Text(self)
        self.text_box.pack()

    def doStuff(self):
        self.text_box.insert(tk.END, "You Pushed the button!\n")
        print("I can print to console though")


class Class3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Class3 Button', command=parent.class3_button)
        button2.pack()

mainGUI()


The issue is because of how you are using Class2 within Class3.
In the Class3 constructor (inside init) you are creating a new instance of Class2 every time the button is clicked, instead of referencing the existing Class2 instance where the text box resides.
You can use callbacks or pass the existing instance of Class2 to Class3 so that Class3 can interact with it directly, without creating a new one. Here is an example with the second option:
class Class1(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    frame2 = Class3(self, self.frame1)  # Pass frame1 to frame2



class Class3(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, frame1):
    super().__init__(parent)
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Class3 Button', command=self.frame1.doStuff)
    button2.pack()

Using callbacks will lead to a less coupled code, but this is another way so you can experiment and keep learning object oriented programming
